# How do I get TLS 1.2 to work in Android 4.4 without the help of Google Play Services?

Tags: android, ssl, android-4.4-kitkat, tls1.2

I have an Android app that strictly runs on a version of Android that cannot use Google Play Services. The app makes data requests via HttpsUrlConnection from a remote server that is being update to only support TLS 1.2 handshaking. I looked at this [blog post](http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/) and tried to implement it but it does not work for me. I know I could get it to work using Google Play Services and updating the SSL Provider, but that is not an option with my specific Android devices. My question is, can I get TLS 1.2 to work on Android 4.4 without the help of Google Play Services?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I ended up installing a copy of Google Play Services from apkmirror.com to solve this issue and use:

```
ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same requirement. i was able enable TLS 1.1+ for Android 4.1 using httpClient 4.1.2
I used this link https://github.com/erickok/transdroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/transdroid/daemon/util/TlsSniSocketFactory.java

Once you include that file in your code, just refer them as in below code.

```
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme("https", new TlsSniSocketFactory(), 443));
client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry),httpParameters);
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: I actually looked at that but it ran into the same issue as using HttpURLConnection. Both still use SSLEngine which still has to be updated from Google Play Services.

Comment: @Kelly No you don't need to. You had to register the class. It worked fine for me. Anyways looks like you found an alternative.

Comment: This worked for me, after many other tries and frustrations. Thank you!

Comment: SchemeRegistry is not available on Android P and newer.